# how to combine with jquery

Tags: jquery

how to combine this into 1 script?

```
$('#tabs, #tabs-1').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui){
    $("#picture").hide();
    }
});

$('#tabs, #tabs-2').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui){
    $("#picture").hide();
    }
});

$('#tabs, #tabs-3').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui){
    $("#picture").hide();
    }
});

$('#tabs, #tabs-4').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui){
    $("#picture").show();
     }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by combine?

Comment: What are you calling `tabs` on `#tabs` 4 times? Don't get it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**Code**

```
$('#tabs, #tabs-1,  #tabs-2, #tabs-3, #tab-4').click(function() {
   var num = $(this).attr('class');

  //get the number at the end of the class of this particular div           
   var lastChar = num.substr(num.length - 1)

  select: function(event, ui){
       if(lastChar == "4")
         $("#picture").show();
       else
        $("#picture").hide();
   }

  });
```